# Python test failing randomly on Azure pipelines on a matplotlib subplots because of Tcl error

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, matplotlib, azure-pipelines, pytest

I have a test failing on a `plt.subplots` call because of a Tcl error.. and I can't figure out why or how to fix it. Here is the test, with the line on which the error is raised:

```
    def test_plot_epoch_segmentation():
        """Test segmentation plots for epochs."""
        n_clusters = 4
        labels = np.random.choice(
            [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3], (len(epochs), epochs.times.size)
        )
    
        plot_epoch_segmentation(labels, epochs, n_clusters)
        plt.close("all")
    
        # provide ax
        f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
        plot_epoch_segmentation(labels, epochs, n_clusters, axes=ax)
        plt.close("all")
    
        # provide cbar_ax
>>      f, cbar_ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
```

Note that 4 lines above... a similar `plt.subplots` is called and does not raise. Without further due, here is the error raised:

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.13\x64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py:1455: in subplots
    fig = figure(**fig_kw)
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.13\x64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py:808: in figure
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.13\x64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py:949: in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    window = tk.Tk(className="matplotlib")
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <tkinter.Tk object .>, screenName = None, baseName = 'pytest'
className = 'matplotlib', useTk = True, sync = False, use = None

    def __init__(self, screenName=None, baseName=None, className='Tk',
                 useTk=True, sync=False, use=None):
        """Return a new Toplevel widget on screen SCREENNAME. A new Tcl interpreter will
        be created. BASENAME will be used for the identification of the profile file (see
        readprofile).
        It is constructed from sys.argv[0] without extensions if None is given. CLASSNAME
        is the name of the widget class."""
        self.master = None
        self.children = {}
        self._tkloaded = False
        # to avoid recursions in the getattr code in case of failure, we
        # ensure that self.tk is always _something_.
        self.tk = None
        if baseName is None:
            import os
            baseName = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
            baseName, ext = os.path.splitext(baseName)
            if ext not in ('.py', '.pyc'):
                baseName = baseName + ext
        interactive = False
>       self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
E       _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "tcl_findLibrary"

C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.13\x64\lib\tkinter\__init__.py:2270: TclError
```

If anyone has an idea.. any help would be appreciated!